# Accessing values in list for modules in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to refactor some terraform code when doing an upgrade.

I'm using some S3 module that takes some lifecycle configuration rules:

```
module "s3_bucket" {
  source             = "../modules/s3"
  lifecycle_rule = [
    {
      id                                     = "id_name"
      enabled                                = true
      abort_incomplete_multipart_upload = 7

      expiration = {
        days = 7
      }

      noncurrent_version_expiration = {
        days = 7
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is how the resource inside the model looks like:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "main" {
  count  = length(var.lifecycle_rule) > 0 ? 1 : 0
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.main.id
  dynamic "rule" {
    for_each = var.lifecycle_rule
    content {
      id = lookup(lifecycle_rule.value, "id", null)
      enabled = lookup(lifecycle_rule.value, "enabled", null)
      abort_incomplete_multipart_upload = lookup(lifecycle_rule.value, "abort_incomplete_multipart_upload", null)
      filter {
        and {
          prefix = lookup(lifecycle_rule.value, "prefix", null)
          tags   = lookup(lifecycle_rule.value, "tags", null)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Running plan gives me the following error:

```
on ../modules/s3/main.tf line 73, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "main":
  73:       id = lookup(lifecycle_rule.id, null)

A managed resource "lifecycle_rule" "id" has not been declared in
module.s3_bucket.
```

2 questions:

1 - Looks like I'm not reaching the lifecycle_rule.value attribute in the list for the module, any help with the syntax?

2 - How to access the nested *expiration.days* value inside the module also?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of your question: you need to use the `rule` and not `lifecycle_rule` [1]. Make sure you understand this part:

> The iterator argument (optional) sets the name of a temporary variable that represents the current element of the complex value. If omitted, the name of the variable defaults to the label of the dynamic block.

To complete the answer, accessing `expiration.days` is possible if you define a corresponding argument in the module. In other words, you need to add `expiration` block to the module code [2].

There are a couple more issues with the code you currently have:

1. The `abort_incomplete_multipart_upload` is a configuration block, the same as `expiration`
2. The expiration date should not be set in number of days, rather an RFC3339 format [3]
3. The `enabled` value cannot be a bool, it has to be either `Enabled` or `Disabled` (mind the first capital letter) and the name of the argument is `status` [4] not `enabled`

To sum up, here's what the code in the module should look like:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration" "main" {
  count  = length(var.lifecycle_rule) > 0 ? 1 : 0
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.main.id
  dynamic "rule" {
    for_each = var.lifecycle_rule
    content {
      id = lookup(rule.value, "id", null)
      status = lookup(rule.value, "enabled", null)
      abort_incomplete_multipart_upload {
        days_after_initiation = lookup(rule.value, "abort_incomplete_multipart_upload", null) 
      } 
      filter {
        and {
          prefix = lookup(rule.value, "prefix", null)
          tags   = lookup(rule.value, "tags", null)
        }
      }
      expiration {
        date = lookup(rule.value.expiration, "days", null)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The module should be called with the following variable values:

```
module "s3_bucket" {
  source             = "../modules/s3"
  lifecycle_rule = [
    {
      id                                     = "id_name"
      enabled                                = "Enabled" # Mind the value
      abort_incomplete_multipart_upload = 7

      expiration = {
        days = "2022-08-28T15:04:05Z" # RFC3339 format
      }

      noncurrent_version_expiration = {
        days = 7
      }
    }
```

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks

[2] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration#expiration

[3] https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339#section-5.8

[4] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_lifecycle_configuration#status